# Is there a way to get all files from a blob of azure

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I need to compare from a list that I have to the files in a blob storage of azure, the only part I  need is a way to get a list of the files in that blob.

For example

> ```
> blob azureImages
> files:
> name
> something.jpg
> asd.jpg
> iwda.jpg
> ```

```
my list:
name
something.jpg
asd.jpg
```

When I compare the files from the blob with my list, I'd like to delete the files that have no match in my list.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get a list of blobs in a container with [CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azurestorage-8.1.3) or inside a directory with [CloudBlobDirectory.ListBlobs()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobs?view=azurestorage-8.1.3)

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint, new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountKey));

//Get a reference to the container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");

//List blobs and directories in this container
var blobs = container.ListBlobs();

foreach (var blobItem in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Uri);
}
```

You'll need to parse the file name from blobItem.Uri, but then you can use LINQ's Except() method to find the difference:

```
public string FindFilesToDelete(IEnumerable<string> fromAzure, IEnumerable<string> yourList)
{
     return fromAzure.Except(yourList);
}
```

which will return everything in the fromAzure list that isn't in yourList.

And lastly you can delete the blobs with [this example](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/#delete-blobs)

Comment: I have this structure  container/folder1/folder2/folder3/myfile.txt. Container.ListBlobs return  upto folder1 only.  Is there a way to get all files, say in folder3?

Comment: @AllenKing after `GetContainerReference("container")`, do `var blobs = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference("folder1/folder2/folder3").ListBlobs();` That will return all blobs in folder3.